# glm.nb link function in MASS package not working when using variable within function call?

Tags: r

When I use an object that stores the link function for the MASS package's `glm.nb` function, the function errors out. However, when I just hard-code the link function, it works fine. I think this has to be due to some sort of environmental referencing gone wrong in their source code, but wanted to be certain before emailing the authors. So, any insight is appreciated here.

**MWE**

```
# Simulate some data
set.seed(666)
n = 1000
x = cbind(1, rnorm(n))
b = c(1,-2)
lam = exp(x%*%b)
y = rnbinom(n, size=.3, mu = lam)

# get package
if(!("MASS" %in% rownames(installed.packages())) 
    install.packages("MASS")
library(MASS)
```

**Attempt 1** -- Define link as parameter default

```
# Define some wrapper function around glm.nb

mfn = function(y, x, mylink = "log"){
  
  MASS::glm.nb(y ~ x - 1, link=mylink)
  
}


# Call mfn on simulated data

mfn(y, x)

> Error in poisson(link = mylink) : object 'mylink' not found


# Call with explicit link in mfn

mfn(y = y, x = x, mylink="log")

>  Error in poisson(link = mylink) : object 'mylink' not found
```

---

**Attempt 2** -- Modifying `mfn` to define `mylink` in function environment

```
# Redefine function

mfn = function(y, x){
  
  mylink = "log" 

  MASS::glm.nb(y ~ x - 1, link=mylink)
  
}


# Call on simulated data

mfn(y = y, x = x)

> Error in poisson(link = mylink) : object 'mylink' not found
```

---

**Attempt 3** Combine (1) and (2)

```
# Redefine mfn

mfn = function(y, x, mylink = "log"){
    
  mylink = "log"
   
  MASS::glm.nb(y ~ x - 1, link = mylink)
  
}


mfn(y = y, x = x, mylink="log")

> Error in poisson(link = mylink) : object 'mylink' not found
```

**Just to be sure** -- Hard-code link function

```
mfn = function(y, x){
  
  mylink = "log"
  MASS::glm.nb(y ~ x - 1, link="log")
  
}

mfn(y = y, x = x)

> Call:  MASS::glm.nb(formula = y ~ x - 1, link = "log", init.theta = 0.2953628307)

Coefficients:
     x1       x2  
 0.9415  -1.9165  

Degrees of Freedom: 1000 Total (i.e. Null);  998 Residual
Null Deviance:      6191 
Residual Deviance: 853.8    AIC: 4248
```

So its pretty clear that there is some sort of referencing issue going on, but I can't immediately find it in the source code nor do I know of a simpler way to test the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I've reached out to the MASS package maintainers, and Bill Venables kindly responded with a working solution for me. For completeness, I've pasted it below:

```
### negative binomial with parametric link function

ngb <- function(formula, data = list(), link) {
  stopifnot(require(MASS))
  thisCall <- substitute(MASS::glm.nb(formula = FORM, data = DATA, link = LINK),
                         list(FORM = substitute(formula),
                              DATA = substitute(data),
                              LINK = link))
  eval.parent(thisCall)
}

library(MASS)
set.seed(5678)
N <- 1000
dummy_data <- within(data.frame(x = rnorm(N)), {
  eta <- 1 - 2*x
  mu <- exp(eta)
  y <- rnegbin(eta, mu, theta = 3)
}) 

tst1 <- ngb(y ~ x, dummy_data, link = "log")

attach(dummy_data)
tst2 <- ngb(y ~ x, link = "log")
detach()

tst3 <- ngb(y ~ poly(x, 2), dummy_data, link = "log")

rbind(coef(tst1), coef(tst2))

summary(tst3)
```

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Try the assignment operator (`<-`) instead of the equals sign (`=`) when you set the function to the name `mfn`.</strike>

It appears that the `MASS::glm.nb` function does some non-standard evaluation (NSE) on the link parameter. If you look at the documentation, the input is an unquoted `log`, with other options as `sqrt` and `identity`. Again note the missing quotes around them.

Without getting too into NSE, I think the simplest solution is to use `...` as a parameter and just pass in the link argument again. This should still give you the flexibility to change your model and add more parameters if you so choose.

```
set.seed(666)
n = 1000
x = cbind(1, rnorm(n))
b = c(1,-2)
lam = exp(x%*%b)
y = rnbinom(n, size=.3, mu = lam)

mfn <- function(y, x, ...){
  MASS::glm.nb(y ~ x - 1, ...)
}

# Call mfn on simulated data
mfn(y, x, link = log)
```

which outputs

```
Call:  MASS::glm.nb(formula = y ~ x - 1, link = log, init.theta = 0.2953628307)

Coefficients:
     x1       x2  
 0.9415  -1.9165  

Degrees of Freedom: 1000 Total (i.e. Null);  998 Residual
Null Deviance:      6191 
Residual Deviance: 853.8    AIC: 4248
```

As a side note in case you want to see how the `MASS::glm.nb` function is doing this object manipulation, you can see it in the first few lines of the source code by typing in the function name without parentheses.

```
MASS::glm.nb
# function (formula, data, weights, subset, na.action, start = NULL, 
#     etastart, mustart, control = glm.control(...), method = "glm.fit", 
#     model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, ..., 
#     init.theta, link = log) 
# {
#     loglik <- function(n, th, mu, y, w) sum(w * (lgamma(th + 
#         y) - lgamma(th) - lgamma(y + 1) + th * log(th) + y * 
#         log(mu + (y == 0)) - (th + y) * log(th + mu)))
#     link <- substitute(link)  <--- This is the line that is messing things up
#     ...
```

Comment: Nope, `<-` and `=` are effectively equivalent (a few minor differences, this is not one of them). Further, I ran your first code block and got the same error as the OP. This might be an R or MASS version problem. I'm on R-4.0.3 (win10_64), MASS-7.3.53, what about you?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working for me still. What version of MASS are you using? Maybe this comes down to versioning...I am using `packageVersion("MASS") > 7.3.53` with R version 4.0.3 on a GNU-Linux machine.

Comment: @r2evans you beat me to it. You and I are using the same version, so this could well be versioning. Although, I'm curious what version EricLeung is using, may help us to be certain.

Comment: I'm still on R 3.6.1. Agreed, the `<-` and `=` are effectively the same. Just something outside of convention that I thought I'd try. With the `=` sign, I did get the same error as OP. Also I'm at MASS 7.3.51.6, all done on a Windows computer.

Comment: Tested and still fails on win10_64, R-3.6.1, MASS-7.3.51.4.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and I think its a non-standard evaluation thing that the `MASS::glm.nb` function does behind the scenes. See my updated answer above.

Comment: The `glm.nb` function seems to look for `mylink` in the global environment. As a hackish workaround you could export `mylink` from within your `mfn` function by adding the line `mylink <<- mylink` before calling `glm.nb`.

Comment: @user12728748 although that is technically possible, changing the global scope within a function like has a code smelly to it (i.e., doesn't sound like a good idea) and acts like a side effect from running the function. But if that works better for OP, then I'd be aware of the issues and communicate it with others who use that function.

Comment: Agh, okay, I think I'll email the maintainers. It doesn't seem reasonable to expect users to pass on arguments as ... rather than as an explicit parameter.

Comment: @John just to add some nuance, this `...` is a feature specific for this non-standard evaluation of the code. All the other parameters for the function `glm.nb` won't need this. The `...` was needed because you're using this particular function in a function, which can complicate these kinds of programming. I hope that helps. Good luck!